# Как мне загрузить несколько изображений?

Tags: php, laravel

***это форма вода***

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="ydostak" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Фото удостоверение с двух сторон') }}</label>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="file" name="image2">
                                </div>

                        </div>
```

***контролер***

```
$target_file_name = public_path().'/upload/'.Str::random(10);
    $type = $_FILES["image2"]["type"];
    $type = stristr($type, '/');
    $type = substr($type, 1);
    $response = array();
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_name.'.'.$type);
    $user->ydostak =basename($request=$target_file_name.'.'.$type );
```

> Мне нужно чтобы можно было добавить несколько изображений

Comment: Что будет, если загрузить в форму файл php?

Comment: Вы либо метку Laravel перестаньте использовать, либо начните документацию читать, чем плодить вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас уже создана форма (проверьте в ней 2 основных атрибута method="post" и enctype="multipart/form-data" ну и action cамо собой)

html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="ydostak" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Фото удостоверение с двух сторон') }}</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="image2[]">
        <input type="file" name="image2[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

php:

```
if (isset($_FILES["image2"])) {
   $files = [];
   $allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
   for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"]); $i++) {
       $ext      = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       $filename = $_FILES['image2']['name'][$i];
       if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
            // error
       }
       $target_file_name = public_path().'/upload/'.Str::random(10);
       $type = $_FILES["image2"]["type"][$i];
       $type = stristr($type, '/');
       $type = substr($type, 1);
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file_name.'.'.$type);
       $files[] = basename($request=$target_file_name.'.'.$type );  // В вашем примере 1 переменная, здесь я чуть поменял       
    }

}
```

Не стал переделывать ваши $type это конечно хардкор, сами уже как-то. Предполагается что с передачей файлов не возникло ошибок иначе нужно добавить проверку с $_FILES["image2"]["error"]

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы загрузить несколько файлов можно создать несколько input'ов:

```
<div class="form-group imageInput">
    <input type="file" name="image2[]">
</div>
<button id="addImageInputButton">Добавить ещё</button>

<script>

var imageInput = document.querySelector('.imageInput');
var addImageInputButton = document.querySelector('#addImageInputButton');
addImageInputButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newImageInput = imageInput.cloneNode(true);
    newImageInput.querySelector('input').value = '';
    this.before(newImageInput);
});

</script>
```

Или можно воспользоваться атрибутом [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple):

```
<div class="form-group imageInput">
    <input type="file" name="image2" multiple>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание на то, что при этом будет в массиве `$_FILES` (`var_dump($_FILES);`). Вам придётся немного переписать код контроллера.

Рекомендую вам сохранять файлы только с допустимыми расширениями. Сейчас если в вашу форму передать php-файл, то вы его сохраните и злоумышленник просто может вызвать его.

Так же обратите внимание, что ларавель предоставляет функции для загрузки файлов (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem).